# How can i make the car visible on top of the background?

Tags: python, pygame, layer, racing

I was confused about how to make the user's car be visible on top of the background. At the moment, when you move the car the track and car move as they should, but the car is under the racetrack. I have tried different blitting orders and i attempted the LayeredUpdates function but it didn't help. I may have been doing it wrong as i am very new to python/pygame. So i would like to know how to get the car to be driving on the track.

Thank you

```
import math
import random

import pygame

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100,16,2,4096)
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 800))
rect = screen.get_rect()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#music
pygame.mixer.music.load("Wice.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.5)
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

WHITE = pygame.Color('white')

VEHICLE1 = pygame.Surface((40, 70), pygame.SRCALPHA)
VEHICLE1.fill((130, 180, 20))
#blitting car onto 'rectangle car'
VEHICLE1 = pygame.image.load("YellowLambo.png")
screen.blit(VEHICLE1,(0,0))
pygame.display.update()

VEHICLE2 = pygame.Surface((40, 70), pygame.SRCALPHA)
VEHICLE2.fill((200, 120, 20))
#blitting computer's car
VEHICLE2 = pygame.image.load("RedLambo.png")
screen.blit(VEHICLE2,(0,0))

BACKGROUND = pygame.Surface((1280, 800))
BACKGROUND.fill((127, 69, 2))
BACKGROUND = pygame.image.load("track1.png").convert()
screen.blit(BACKGROUND,(0,0))
pygame.display.update()


class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)


class VehicleSprite(Entity):
    MAX_FORWARD_SPEED = 10
    MAX_REVERSE_SPEED = 2
    ACCELERATION = 0.05
    TURN_SPEED = 0.000000000001


    def __init__(self, image, position):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.src_image = image
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=position)
        self.position = pygame.math.Vector2(position)
        self.velocity = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.speed = self.direction = 0
        self.k_left = self.k_right = self.k_down = self.k_up = 0

    def update(self, time):
        # SIMULATION
        self.speed += self.k_up + self.k_down
        # To clamp the speed.
        self.speed = max(-self.MAX_REVERSE_SPEED,
                         min(self.speed, self.MAX_FORWARD_SPEED))

        # Degrees sprite is facing (direction)
        self.direction += (self.k_right + self.k_left)
        rad = math.radians(self.direction)
        self.velocity.x = -self.speed*math.sin(rad)
        self.velocity.y = -self.speed*math.cos(rad)
        self.position += self.velocity
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.src_image, self.direction)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.position)


class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, image, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)


def game_loop():
    bike = VehicleSprite(VEHICLE1, rect.center)
    pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates.move_to_front
    ball = VehicleSprite(VEHICLE2, rect.center)

    bike_group = pygame.sprite.Group(bike)
    ball_group = pygame.sprite.Group(ball)
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(bike_group, ball_group)
    background = Background(BACKGROUND, [0, 0])

    camera = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
    done = False

    while not done:
        time = clock.tick(60)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                # Bike Input (Player 1)
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    bike.k_right = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    bike.k_left = 5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    bike.k_up = 2
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    bike.k_down = -2

                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    bike.k_right = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    bike.k_left = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    bike.k_up = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    bike.k_down = 0


        camera -= bike.velocity

        all_sprites.update(time)

        screen.fill(WHITE)
        screen.blit(background.image, background.rect)


        for sprite in all_sprites:
            screen.blit(background.image, background.rect.topleft+camera)
            screen.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect.topleft+camera)


        pygame.display.flip()





game_loop()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it makes a difference but have you tried to replace:

```
for sprite in all_sprites:
    screen.blit(background.image, background.rect.topleft+camera)
    screen.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect.topleft+camera)
```

with

```
all_sprites.draw(screen)
```

Comment: thank you for your response. When i try this it shows the cars and the track, however the racing track is still, and does not move. I am attempting to make the car move around the track, where the camera is 'focused' on the car, so as you progress through the circuit, other areas of the track won't be visible as it will appear that the car is progressing through the track.

Answer (score 2):

Look at these lines:

```
    screen.blit(background.image, background.rect)

    for sprite in all_sprites:
        screen.blit(background.image, background.rect.topleft+camera)
        screen.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect.topleft+camera)
```

For each sprite you blit to the screen, you blit the background image again.

I guess you want something like:

```
    screen.blit(background.image, background.rect.topleft+camera)

    for sprite in all_sprites:
        screen.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect.topleft+camera)
```

drawing the background only once.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, when i do this, the background is stable and does not move, so the car will not appear to be progressing through the track.